# Excel Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal

Tags: c#

I have a numeric value with exponential form,I am getting it from an excel file, I am parsing it with decimal.parse. Some values are parsing perfectly but I am getting error "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal." in some values
for eg I have value 8.996812E+31
I am parsing it like this

```
 var cellval = decimal.Parse(colData[j].ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

where colData[j]="8.996812E+31" its giving me exception  Value was either too large or too small for Decimal.

How can I handle this?I tried using double and float but both are showing the value in Exponent, I have to show without exponent and without rounding off

Comment: Don't use `decimal` for Excel cell values, use `double` like Excel does internally

Answer (score 0):

You need to read into a double because the number is larger and won't fit in a decimal.

You can format the output without exponent and round of. See MS documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to data type like BigInteger.

[BigInteger Structure MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

[Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class)